# Working on two different branches for two different releases in sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to sourceTree or git and my team uses it for building apps. All of us are working off of the develop branch which corresponds to the current release (let's say release 1).
I mostly need to work on the upcoming release (release 2). What's the best way/approach for me to create a new branch for release 2?

I had created a feature branch off of the develop branch for release2 which I intend to merge to develop when the release is done for release1. But now, release1 is getting delayed and I fear that we might have merge conflicts. So, what's the best approach to work on two release simultaneously.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 separate branches named release1 and release2 should solve your problem.

Comment: and later merge release1 to main and release2

Comment: Are there any major disadvantages of doing this? I am curious as to why I was told to work on feature branch rather than creating a new release branch.